# data-complete event not working in Mastercard Payment Gateway Checkout.js integration

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, mastercard

I'm using the master card checkout.js method version 57.
There are two types of payments ways.
I want to use only **`showLightbox()`** but unfortunately **`completeCallback()`** function is not working.
I have tried to find solution but everyone is suggesting to send `Interaction.returnUrl` parameter in session request but I don't want redirection.
Here is my code,

```
 <script src="https://dohabank.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.js" 
data-error="errorCallback"
        data-cancel="cancelCallback"
        data-beforeRedirect="beforeRedirect"
        data-afterRedirect="afterRedirect"
        data-complete="completeCallback"
></script>

    function completeCallback(resultIndicator, sessionVersion) {
   alert(resultIndicator);
}


$curl = curl_init();


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://dohabank.gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/57/merchant/TESTDB95810/session",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n \"apiOperation\": \"CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION\",\r\n \"interaction\": {\r\n \"operation\": \"PURCHASE\"\r\n },\r\n \"order\" : {\r\n \"amount\" : \"5.10\",\r\n \"currency\" : \"QAR\",\r\n \"description\": \"Ordered goods\",\r\n \"id\": \"5\"\r\n }\r\n}",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"authorization: Basic Auth Token",
"cache-control: no-cache"
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

// if ($err) {
// echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
// } else {
// echo $response;
// }

// echo $response;
$object = json_decode($response);
$sessionId = $object->{'session'}->id;
//$sessionSuccess = $object->{'successIndicator'};

//echo $sessionId;



echo $sessionId;
```

Comment: As a reminder, the Wordpress tag is for programming-specific questions about the WordPress content management system.

Comment: okay. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution. **`MerchantId`** was missing in `**Checkout.configure()**` method.

Comment: When i added MerchantId i got that error merchantId is not allowed via configure(), deleting... also, whats the difference between checkout.min.js and checkout.js

Comment: Hi, hope all is well. I am currently using firebase as my backend and im starting the integration process with MPGS, will i be able to accomplish it with firebase or will i be to have a nodeJS express server to do that for me?